# Progress Bar in IOHandler.ReadStream

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Is there anyway to make a progress bar in IOHandler.ReadStream ?

> AStream := TFileStream.Create(dlFile, fmCreate + fmShareDenyNone);
> AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream, -1, false);

maybe something like

> while AStream.onProgress do
>
> begin
>
> //for progressbar
>
> end;

or

> repeat
>
> AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream, 4, false);
>
> Progressbar1.Position:=Progressbar1.Position+4;
>
> until AStream.size = maxSize;

Comment: Have a look at the OnWork events of IOHandler